# PHP GET parameter not showing without page refresh

Tags: php, hyperlink, get, refresh, echo

any idea what is wrong here. I generate link list from database. When I click link, it navigates to another page, but echo is missing. However, if I check "View page source", I can found my echo. If I want to see it on page, I need to refresh page manually, so I can see my echo. I don't to refresh page, so any idea what is problem here?

[image: Screenshot]

Source codes:

**page.php:**

```
<?php
    while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo '<li><a href="test.php/?name='.$col_value.'">'.$col_value.'</a></li>';
        }
    }

    // Free resultset
    pg_free_result($result);

    // Closing connection
    pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php
    echo 'TEST ';
    echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
?>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the `/` in `test.php/?` ?

Comment: Why do you need to use the `htmlspecialchars` ? the name should be a plain string without any `html` tags right? Try removing it

Comment: I removed htmlspecialchars, but no effect. But echo 'TEST' is also missing, so I don't think it's link problem. I took this example from: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Yes, i supposed it wasn't there the problem but was just making sure to remove possible silly problems ;)
That's pretty weird.. of course there're no CSS rules that set something like `color: white`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test.php page, replace your code with the following code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
      echo 'TEST ';
      echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
    ?>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Let me know if it works now!

---

**Edited: Explanation of why this solution worked**

The image shown in the question showed 2 windows. The confusion starts there. The window on the left is the browser at work displaying the html code that was rendered, while the window on the right is the "Source Code"! What that means is that the browser probably didn't understand what `TESTHELLO dbName` meant and made a blank page, but when adding all the default tags, then the browser was happy to interpret it as text within the pages body.

Comment: @M4tt No problem! I will edit my answer a bit now explaining what happened :)